# Plone unicode encode

Tags: python, unicode, plone

I'm using Plone 3.1.1 and trying to encode and decode the following string

```
aa = "(｡･ω･｡)ﾉ"
bb = repr( aa )          #output: (\xef\xbd\xa1\xef\xbd\xa5\xcf\x89\xef\xbd\xa5\xef\xbd\xa1)\xef\xbe\x89
print cc.decode("utf-8") #output: (\xef\xbd\xa1\xef\xbd\xa5\xcf\x89\xef\xbd\xa5\xef\xbd\xa1)\xef\xbe\x89
```

I'm wondering why it doesn't output the original string encoded. But if I decode the hex outout it prints the original string.

```
bb = "(\xef\xbd\xa1\xef\xbd\xa5\xcf\x89\xef\xbd\xa5\xef\xbd\xa1)\xef\xbe\x89" 
yy = bb.decode("utf-8")  #output: (｡･ω･｡)ﾉ
```

Basically I want to encode before send it to the database and decode when I'm retrieving.

Comment: `print` encodes to the terminal encoding. The encoding of `aa` is dependent on your source text editor or your terminal encoding if you entered it into the interactive shell.

Comment: How is `aa` *received* by Plone? What database are you storing it in, the ZODB?

Comment: Oh, and this is not in a Python Script in the skin layer, is it?

Comment: First, `print cc.decode("utf-8')` isn't likely to output the original string decoded, because `cc` isn't the same thing as `bb`.

Comment: Second, the `repr` of a string is not an encoding of that string as UTF-8, it's the string with backslash escapes added and quotes placed around it. So, it's hard to imagine why you'd expect decoding as UTF-8 to reverse that.

Comment: aa received as a POST from front end. We use using database is mssql

Comment: I _think_ your confusion is that, in a non-raw string literal, `\xef` is a single character, character number 0xEF. You're probably trying to decode a string with the four characters `\`, `x`, `e`, and `f` in it, which will not do the same thing as decoding a string with the single character `\xef` in it. You may want to try some of this stuff in a Python command-line app or in the interactive interpreter before trying it in Plone, to eliminate a lot of the irrelevant stuff that's just adding confusion.

Comment: I haven't checked if it is the case here, but since there are [several different normalization forms in Unicode](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Norm_Forms), you can't safely assume that your source string stays the same byte-for-byte even if you just do non-destructive transformations.